# Joint probability function for the values of a free field at two different points

Tags: quantum-field-theory

For a free real field $\phi$ in its ground state, is there a way to find the probability distribution $p(\phi_x,\phi_y)$ for joint measurement of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ at two spacelike-separated points $x$, $y$?

Presumably the information needed to construct $p(\phi_x,\phi_y)$ would be contained in the expectation values of products of powers of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$, since we could invert the formula
$$
E[\phi(x)^n\phi(y)^m] = \int d\phi_xd\phi_y p(\phi_x,\phi_y)\phi_x^n\phi_y^m
$$
but the expectation values are divergent for $n$ or $m$ greater than $1$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. By *joint measurement*, do you mean we look at the observable $\phi(x)\phi(y)$ and measure it? Also, this probability distribution...looks *suspiciously* like you would like to know about the [path integral approach to expectation values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation#Expectation_values) (since it seems you never heard of it. If yes, I apologize. If no, note that *Explain the path integral to me* is probably too broad for this site)

Comment: @ACuriousMind Apologies for the unclearness: By "joint measurement" I mean we measure both $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$, finding the value of both (not just a value for their product). Since the fields commute at spacelike separation I don't think there is any problem with doing that. I know I could write $p(\phi_x,\phi_y)$ as the path integral over functions $\phi(x)$ of $|\Psi[\phi]|^2$ with the constraints $\phi(x)=\phi_x$, $\phi(y)=\phi_y$ ($\Psi$ is the wavefunctional of the ground state). I do not see an easy way to evaluate this, but I will try.

Comment: Is $|<\Omega|\phi_a>|^2$ the probability to measure the (time-independent) field configuration $\phi_a(x)$ throughout all of space? I think so. So you want to measure it only in two points in space time. So why not integrate over all field values in points you _don't_ want to measure and thus you get your result?